# How to make height correspond to width

Tags: html, css

I am working on images with CSS and added this rule to the style sheet:

```
.sideimage {
  width: 200px;
}
```

What this does to the images is that it makes the width `200px` but the height is still the original one so the images are now out of proportion (the height is far too long).

I tried adding `height: auto;` to the rule but it didn't help:

```
.sideimage {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

There must be a simple solution to this but I haven't been able to come across it yet.

This is what the html looks like (not sure what is meant by stacksnippet):

```
<section>
<img class="sideimage" src="images/helgafell.jpg" alt="Helgafell">
<h1>Helgafell</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML too? CSS alone doesn't go far in troubleshooting.

Comment: <section><img class="sideimage" src="images/helgafell.jpg" alt="Helgafell"><h1>Helgafell</h1></section>

Comment: Checkout my example. It should fix the problem for you :)

Comment: @Stefania Can you edit the question and add that in. Vital info like that is supposed to be in the question itself, not in comments. And while you're at it, turn it into a stacksnippet that we can test.

Comment: @MrLister Does that matter? You want to set width / height of DOM element. You don't need to know what the element actually is. Why did you give me negative rating?